# I'm using the ajax .load method when but it only loads the content for a second then disappears

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i would include a jsfiddle but ajax doesn't work in them

```css
 <script>// loads the survay quesitons using ajax
 function sendAJAX() {
   $('#ajax').load('survey.html');
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/code.css" TYPE="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <form class="name" method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />

    <button id="load" onclick="sendAJAX()" class="button">Next</button>

    <div id="ajax">

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

this is the code it should be loading

```
<div class= "section">


    <img src="img/mbeef.png" alt="Beef" class="choices" data-value="11"> 
    <img src="img/mbacon.png" alt="Bacon" class="choices" data-value="12">
    <br>

    <button class="name" id="btn-show">Submit</button>
```

## **[a live example](http://tdring.com/ramen/index.html)**

it also doesn't work when i put the script into my javascript.js file

### edit

i changed my code to

```
// loads the survay quesitons using ajax
        function sendAJAX(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ajax').load('survey.html');
}   
      </script>
```

and now im getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is most likely posting back since your `button` is in a `form`, try using `preventDefault`

```
<button id="load" onclick="sendAJAX(event)" class="button">Next</button>

function sendAJAX(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#ajax').load('survey.html');
}
```

Comment: its now saying "Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined "

Comment: Did you include `event` in the HTML? @tearisha

Comment: You did not pass the event parameter in your onclick. This is a perfect example why you shoulkd not inline-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's the submitting of the page (well, the form). The page reloads because of the normal submit does not get stopped.

You have to stop the event, jQuery has [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for that. You can either block the submitbutton:

```
$('#load').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // stop the 'click' event
    $('#ajax').load('survey.html');
});
```

This will block submitting the via button. But the form can still get submitted, so you can stop the submitting of the form itself:

```
$('form.name').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // stop the 'submit' event
    $('#ajax').load('survey.html');
});
```

Comment: i thought i was loading the html into the div with the id ajax?

Answer (score -1):

Set the type attribute of button.

```
<button id='load' onclick='sendAJAX()' type='button' class='button'>Next</button>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This still has nothing to do with it :)